# VS Code: How to make IntelliSense activate with Ctrl+Space but still allow quick info?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm used to Eclipse, NetBeans, and PHPStorm, and am stumbling through VS Code and not easily finding how to config or fix annoyances, like the editor auto-popping down suggestions while I type, meaning if I hit Enter before realizing it's showing the suggestion, it changes what I typed.

I found this was IntelliSense, but I'm used to suggestions popping up only after hitting Ctrl+Space. When I discover quickSuggestions in Settings, the other non-false option I understand there is "other" (true), but setting that to false makes no suggestions show even when hitting Ctrl+Space.

When I find out what Ctrl+Space actually does, it's listed as "quick info" on IntelliSense's help page - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense - but "quick info" is not found in a search in Settings or Keymap... *super frustrating*.

So I'm kind of stumbling through seemingly wasting a lot of time of my workday trying to config things to be less annoying and disruptive... any guidance here or do I need to take a class?

Comment: Even if all items in `editor.quickSuggestions` set to `false` it still should trigger suggestion on `ctrl`+`space`.

Answer (score 3):

Disable using <kbd>Enter</kbd> as accept trigger:

```json
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is used to trigger suggest and when suggest is visible to trigger "quick info":

[image]

You can find keybindings in [default keybindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization). Invoke Go to Symbol <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

[image]